# Formatting bible verse reference with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to monospace bibleverse references so that single digit chapters or verses have a leading space.

So "4:5" becomes " 4: 5" and "3:21" becomes " 3:21".

I'm really having problems writing the regex, please help.

I've tried many variations but they essentially boil down to (^\d|\d$), (^\d{1}|\d{1}$) and (^[^0-9]\d|[^0-9]\d$) and many combinations between them

```
    inRef = inChapter + ':' + inVerse;
    var inReg = /(^[0-9]{1}|[^0-9][0-9]{1}$)/g;     
    inRef = inRef.replace(inReg,"&nbsp;$1");
    console.log(inRef);
```

Alot of the results I'm getting from my efforts turn references like "6:15" into " 6: 1 5" or " 6:1 5"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the strings `inChapter` and `inVerse`, you could do something like this:

```
inRef = ("  " + inChapter).slice(-2) + ":" + ("  " + inVerse).slice(-2)
```

Note there are two spaces there `"  "` and I'm assuming `inChapter` and `inVerse` are only ever 1 or 2 digits.

Edit: Since you need three digits and I assume you still want these to line up, you could do this:

```
var pad = "   ";   // this is now THREE spaces! 
inRef = (pad + inChapter).slice(-pad.length) + ":" + (pad + inVerse).slice(-pad.length)
```

So now if you run all your `inChapter` and `inVerse` pairs through this, you should get strings that line up like this:

```
100:100
 20:100
  2:100
100: 10
100:  1
 10: 10
 10:  1
  1:  1
```

Comment: /facepalm (mine). Nope, Psalms has more than 100 chapters, and some chapters have more than 100 verses.

Comment: @user3917091: Well then, don't you need to line those up too? In that case just substitute 3 spaces instead of 2 in my answer. (or you could just create a separate variable to make this a little easier).

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort! I've been testing on Genesis so long and it's not a long book and no long chapters that I'd completely forgotten there was anything longer.

Answer (score 3):

Why a regex at all? You've already got the chapter/verse as separate data BEFORE you combined them into the `x:y` format, so do the formatting there while they're still seperate strings:

```
if (inChapter.length == 1) { inChapter = ' ' + inChapter }
inRef = inChapter + ':' + inVerse;
```

Using a regex for this uber-simplistic transformation is akin to nuking a city to get some dust off a shelf instead of using a feather duster.

Comment: It's part of a loop and it seemed like regex would be the better option than doing two ifs for each iteration (once for chapter and once for verse).

Comment: an if() test has essentially ZERO overhead compared to having to instantiate/parse/execute a regex.